# How to put folders to different branches?

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I haven't used git for 2 years and it is giving me a hard time now when I look back my at old work. :(

Basically, I have one folder (the main folder) which I want to push to a branch called `source` and there is a folder inside the main folder named `_deploy` which I want to push to the master branch of the same repo. when I do the following!

`$ git checkout -b source (on main folder)
   $ git push -u origin source
   $ cd _deploy
   $ git checkout -b master
   $ git push -u origin master`

I get something weird. On my github repo, I see in both the branches, the same folders and `_deploy` in black, which means I am not able to see inside `_deploy`. However, this should only happen if I view the branch `source` not `master`. `master` branch should show me the content inside `_deploy`.

Background:
    This is a jekyll blog.
    I have done `git init` in the main folder and have added remote origin to the main folder as well. Please help me understand and solve if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `cd _deploy` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your Github page and saw that your `_deploy` folder is now accessible from both branches. It seems like you would like to clean up the branch now? I have an assumption what happened, please let me know if it is correct.

You have initialised your repository using `git init` and then proceeded by adding your files and folders to Git. Probably by running `git add .` followed by a `git commit -m "Init Message"`. Which will put all your files — except of the ones mentioned in `.gitignore`under version control.

Then you used `git checkout -b source` **which branched off of your last commit which included all files**. That's the reason, why you got the same files in master and source.

To remove the folders only from the version control, but not on your disk, you can run the following commands.

```
git rm --cached ./_deploy
git commit -m "Remove deploy"
```

**A little side-note:** Changing the directory in your terminal (`cd _deploy`) will **not** affect your git branch / git status.

Comment: Hi! Yes it is visible from both the branches now. However, I wanted to see only the content inside `_deploy` in my master branch. Like I have done here https://github.com/talkstwor/talkstwor.github.io . you can check the build.sh which I used to use before to commit after changes. However, initially how to set it up I don't know so that my main folder only pushes to `source` branch and `_deploy` pushes to `master` branch.

Comment: Within your shell script, you enter the folder `cd _deploy` and run `git add .` _assuming_ that it will only add files within this folder. This is not the case. `git add .` adds all files within the main main folder. What you would like to do it `git add ./_deploy` instead.